# Square of a random variable that converges in probability to a constant

Tags: probability-theory

I'm using the textbook "An Introduction to Probability and Statistics 2E" (Vijai K. Rohatgi), and it states the following result (*"the truth of the following statements can easily be verified"*, pp. 260, property 6):

If $X_n \overset{p}{\to} k$ (where $k$ is a constant), then $X_n^2 \overset{p}{\to} k^2$.

Here are some proof attempts that led me nowhere:

## Attempt #1

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|X_n^2 - k^2 \right| > c\}$

$ \le \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{X_n^2 - k^2 > c\} + P\{X_n^2 - k^2 < -c\}$

$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{X_n^2 > k^2 + c\} + P\{X_n^2 < k^2 -c\}$

$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{X_n > \sqrt{k^2 + c} \;\lor\; X_n < -\sqrt{k^2 + c}\} + P\{X_n < \sqrt{k^2 -c} \;\lor\; X_n > -\sqrt{k^2 -c} \}$

$ \le \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{X_n > \sqrt{k^2 + c}\} + P\{X_n < -\sqrt{k^2 + c}\} + P\{X_n < \sqrt{k^2 -c}\} + P\{X_n > -\sqrt{k^2 -c} \}$

= 1

## Attempt #2

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|X_n^2 - k^2 \right| > c\}$

$= \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|(X_n + k)(X_n - k) \right| > c\}$

$= \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|(X_n + k)\right| \cdot \left|(X_n - k) \right| > c\}$

$\le \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|(X_n + k)\right| > \sqrt{c}\} + P\{\left|(X_n - k) \right| > \sqrt{c}\}$

$= \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|(X_n + k)\right| > \sqrt{c}\} + 0$

$= \lim_{n \to \infty} P\{\left|(X_n + k)\right| > \sqrt{c}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given any $\epsilon$ there exists $\epsilon'$ so that the set $A=\{x ,s.t. |x^2-k^2|>\epsilon\}$ is included into $B=\{x ,s.t. |x-k|>\epsilon'\}$, so that one can bound the measures of the first set by the other. Convince yourself geometrically first, i.e. plotting the parabola, 
and than estimate the limit.

You will notice that similar reasonings apply for any continuous function not just a parabola

Answer (score 0):

$|X_n-k| <\delta$ implies $|X_n^{2}-k^{2}| <\delta |X_n+k| <\delta(|X_n-k|+2|k|)<\delta(\delta+2|k|)$. Given $\epsilon >0$ we can choose $\delta >0$ such that $\delta(\delta+2|k|)<\epsilon$. Note that $|X_n^{2}-k^{2}| \geq \epsilon$ implies $|X_n-k| \geq \delta$. Hence $P(|X_n^{2}-k^{2}| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n-k| \geq \delta) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.